# pass 2d array from code behind to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a DataTable that I get from the DB, I want to create a 2d array in the code behind (once I get the DataTable..), and then pass it as a 2d array to Javascript.

this is what I tried to code :

```
int[,] videoQarray = new int[dt_questionVideo.Rows.Count,dt_questionVideo.Columns.Count ];
        string[,] videoQarrayTitle = new string[dt_questionVideo.Rows.Count, dt_questionVideo.Columns.Count ];

        for (var i = 0; i < dt_questionVideo.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt_questionVideo.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                videoQarray[i,j] = Convert.ToInt32(dt_questionVideo.Rows[i][0]);
                videoQarrayTitle[i,j] = dt_questionVideo.Rows[i][1].ToString();   
            }
        }

        string createArrayScript = string.Format("var videQarray = [{0}];", string.Join(",", videoQarray));
        createArrayScript += string.Format("var videQarrayList = [{0}];", string.Join(",", videoQarrayTitle));

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "registerVideoQArray", createArrayScript, true);
```

well, in the browser console it says that videoQarray is not defined.. 
I wonder how can I do that properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the variable is being defined inside a function and therefore is hidden for other parts of code. Try "window.videoQArray" insted of "var ":

```
string createArrayScript = string.Format("window.videQarray = [{0}];", string.Join(",", videoQarray));
createArrayScript += string.Format("window.videQarrayList = [{0}];", string.Join(",", videoQarrayTitle));
```

Edit: It's a 2d array (ok, you wrote that very clearly in the question but I didn't see). Use `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string createArrayScript = string.Format("window.videQarray = {0};", serializer.Serialize(videoQarray));
createArrayScript += string.Format("window.videQarrayList = {0};", serializer.Serialize(videoQarrayTitle));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use The following function:

```
 public static string ArrayToString2D(string[,] arr)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("[['");
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < arr.GetLength(1); l++)
            {
                if (arr[k, l] == null)
                    str.Append("','");
                else
                    str.Append(arr[k, l].ToString() + "','");
            }
            str.Remove(str.Length - 2, 2);
            str.Append("],['");
        }
        str.Remove(str.Length - 4, 4);
        str.Append("]]");
        return str.ToString();
    }
```

in the code behind have the following properties:

```
private string[,] upperLabels ;
    public string UpperLabel
    {
        get
        { return Utils.ArrayToString2D(upperLabels); }
    }
```

in the javascript use the following :

```
var upperSplitted = <%=UpperLabel%> ;
var value = upperSplitted[0][0];
```